# Flask URL Parameters with % Are Not Properly Handled

Tags: python, url, flask, encoding, werkzeug

EDIT2: I apologize for the lack of clarity.
I will provide several values. The first is the URL that I call using my frontend app. The second is the value before calling `urllib.unquote`. The third is the value after calling `urlib.unquote`.

frontend:

```
console.log('http://localhost:8080/v1/' + encodeURIComponent(name))
```

backend:

```
def f(param=''):
    print('*', param)
    param = urllib.unquote(param)
    print('**', param)
```

Ex.

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
* https:%2F%2Fgoogle.com
** https://google.com
```

Ex2.

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/foo%2520bar
* foo%20bar
** foo bar
```

Ex3.

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/foo%20bar
* foo bar
** foo bar
```

Thank you for being patient and helping me with this. I apologize for being unclear in my original post.

EDIT: In short, if I call `/v1/%2520`, param is equal to `" "` at the end of the function, instead of `"%20"`, at the beginning of the function it is equal to `"%20"` and not `"%2520"`.

I'm currently working on a Flask App using Python 2.7.

I'm trying to create a function which can handle URL parameters.

```
@app.route('/v1/<param>', methods=['DELETE'])
def f(param=''):
    param = urllib.unquote(param)
```

On my frontend application, I call this function by encoding the `param`. However, if I pass `"foo bar"` and `"foo%20bar"` to the function, the `param` is resolved to the same value -- `"foo bar"`, when really `"foo bar"` should be `"foo bar"` and `"foo%20bar"` should be `"foo%20bar"`.

Due to this bug, I am unable to delete the `"foo%20bar"` entry. If I try to delete it, it will delete `"foo bar"`, and once `"foo bar"` is deleted, the `"foo%20bar"`entry will never be deleted.

I believe this is because `"%20"` is not equal to `"%2520"` even though that is what the param is. When I print this value before calling `urllib.unquote(param)` it is already equal to `"%20"`. Then, when I call `urllib.unquote(param)` the value is changed to `" "`.

I'm not really sure if this is a bug in Flask/Werkzeug, but it is causing my application to not work.

Do you have any suggestions for fixing this issue? Thanks!

Comment: No, `foo%20bar` ***is*** `foo bar`. Even `foo bar` in the browser URL bar is actually sent to the server as `foo%20bar`. If you really wanted `foo%20bar` after URL decoding, then send `foo%2520bar`.

Comment: Sorry. I must have been unclear. `"foo%2520bar"` is equal to `"foo%20bar"` BEFORE I modify the value using `urllib.unquote`. So if I call `/v1/foo%2520bar`, the param value is equal to `"foo bar"` instead of `"foo%20bar"` @MartijnPieters

Comment: So why are you using `urllib.unquote()` at all then?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I will be passing URLs to the param.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Flask is usually handling percent encoding *exactly right*. Parameters in a URL are percent encoded, and these are decoded for you when the WSGI environment is set up. Flask then passes this on to your route when matching.

You do **not** need to decode the parameter value again, remove your `urllib.unquote()` call.

Your browser will actually encode spaces in the URL to `%20` for you, even though the location bar will show a space. The location bar decodes percent-encoded components to make it possible to read international characters (so `%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%82%82%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86` is shown as `どうもありがとう`, for example).

If you are having issues with encoded slashes (`/`, `%2F`), then see [issue #900](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/900), there are edge cases with Apache directives (and other WSGI servers) to consider. You would need to use a `<path:param>` component to match those, because the default `string` parameter type will not match slashes.

If I use the following test script, named `routetest.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
try:
    from urllib.parse import unquote  # PY3
except ImportError:
    from urllib import unquote  # PY2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/v1/<path:param>')  # NOTE: <path:param> is required to match /
def f(param=''):
    return (
        f"param: {param}\ndecoded param: {unquote(param)}\n",
        200,
        {'content-type': 'text/plain'}
    )
```

use `FLASK_APP=routetest flask run` to launch this script on `localhost:5000`, then I can't reproduce your issues:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/v1/https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
param: https://google.com
decoded param: https://google.com
$ curl http://localhost:5000/v1/foo%2520bar
param: foo%20bar
decoded param: foo bar
$ curl http://localhost:5000/v1/foo%20bar
param: foo bar
decoded param: foo bar
```

which can only mean that you have a WSGI server that is mishandling quoting in paths.