# How to handle several parameters containing slashes?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app to which I need to pass several parameters containing slashes. For example, I have  `parameter1 = "Clothes/Bottoms"` and `parameter2 = "Pants/Jeans"`. I tried doing it this way:

In my HTML/JS:

```js
par1 = encodeURIComponent(parameter1);
par2 = encodeURIComponent(parameter2);
console.log("Par1 = ",par1," par2 = ",par2);
$.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:'/get_data'+'/'+par1+'/'+par2,
     ....
});
```

and in my `app.py`:

```py
 @app.route('/get_data/<path:par1>/<path:par2>/',methods=['GET','POST'])
 def get_data(par1, par2):
     print("In get_data with par1 ",par1," and par2 ",par2)
     ....
```

I can see from Javascript print-outs that both parameters look fine after being encoded, but then the Python print out is:

```
 In get_data with par1 Clothes and par2 Bottoms/Pants/Jeans
```

So it somehow mistakes the slash in `par1`'s `"Clothes/Bottoms"` for part of the URL and shifts `"Bottoms"` into `par2`.

Is there a better way to handle multiple parameters with slashes than just adding `path:`?

Comment: Do you always have one slash in each parameter? Or can that vary?

Comment: It can vary - for example, parameter2 can go pretty far down in the clothing hierarchy.

Comment: It might be better to just switch to another character; it seems from e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55246562/3001761 that Flask receives the path *without* the encoding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `/get_data/<path:par1>/<path:par2>/`, there's no way for Flask to "know" which slash is the separator when it receives a request like `/get_data/Clothes/Bottoms/Pants/Jeans/`.

If the number of slashes in `par1` is fixed, you could receive the path as a single parameter and then split it into two:

```
@app.route('/get_data/<path:pars>/')
def get_data(pars):
     par1 = '/'.join(pars.split("/",2)[:2]) #par1 is everything up until the 2nd slash
     par2 = pars.split("/",2)[2:][0] #par2 is everything after the second slash
```

Otherwise, you could simply replace the separator slash with another character like:

```
@app.route('/get_data/<path:par1>-<path:par2>/')
```

Answer (score 3):

To understand flask (werkzeug) routing. Take aside encoding you used in JavaScript for a second.

Regex pattern used by werkzeug's `path` converter is `[^/].*?`. This allow any number of `/` in url path. Which means only part1 `get_data/<path:par1>` can accepts both `get_data/Clothes/Bottoms` or `get_data/Clothes/Bottoms/Pants/Jeans`.

You are using two `path` convertor in part1 and par2  which is bad as one part1 can take all slash.

**Now the other issue. why even after encoding url its not working as expected**.

Flask uses Werkzeug default WSGI server. And WSGI library unescaped uri before using it for routing. i.e., `get_data/Clothes%2FBottoms` gets converted to `get_data/Clothes/Bottoms` when it comes to routing.
in your case router receives `get_data/Clothes/Bottoms/Pants/Jeans` here it takes is "Clothes" as part1 and rest as part2.

Refer to  [flask issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/900) regarding this.

**Solution**

Double escape in JavaScript could be workaround here.
`path` converter can also be replaced by `string`.

```
par1 = encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(parameter1));
par2 = encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(parameter2));

$.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:'http://localhost:8000/get_data'+'/'+par1+'/'+par2+'/'});
```

And decode at flask application to get back your strings

```
from urllib import unquote_plus
@app.route('/get_data/<string:par1>/<string:par2>/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_data(par1, par2):
    print unquote_plus(par1),  unquote_plus(par1)
```